# Generic return types in traits for implementations that return non object-safe traits

Tags: rust, types, rust-tokio, serde

I'm new to Rust and I wanted to learn the language and get a better understanding by implementing some small projects. My first attempt was to parse JSON data received from an MQTT Broker.
I was very pleased how easy it was to accomplish this with the help of `tornado` and `serde`. However, there quickly arose a pattern that I wanted to (ideally) extract into a Trait.

```rust
let person_stream = sender.subscribe().filter_map(|data| {
    if let Ok(value) = data {
        return serde_json::from_slice::<Person>(&value).ok();
    }
    None
});
```

where `sender` typically is a `tokio::sync::*::Sender` and `Person` would implement the `serde::de::DeserializeOwned` Trait.

So the goal was to implement something that takes a `tokio::stream::StreamExt<Item = Vec<u8>>` and `transform` it into another `StreamExt` where the associated type `Item` would implement `DeserializOwned`.

It took me quite some time to figure something out (since I originally wanted to use a Trait or a function with generics) and I came up with

```rust
fn transform<T, U, V>(stream: U) -> impl StreamExt<Item = T>
where
    T: serde::de::DeserializeOwned,
    U: StreamExt<Item = Result<Vec<u8>, V>>,
{
    stream.filter_map(|data| {
        if let Ok(value) = data {
            return serde_json::from_slice::<T>(&value).ok();
        }
        None
    })
}
```

While this works I originally wanted a Trait like

```rust
trait Transform<T>
{
    fn transform(self) -> T;
}
```

or implement `Into` which is actually the same, which I could implement for `StreamExt<Item = Vec<u8>>`. Since `impl Trait` return is not available for Traits this was the only option I thought I had. However, I'm facing a couple of issues implementing this.

1. Using `tokio::stream::filter_map::FilterMap<_,_>` for `T` (which is the return type of `filter_map()`) is not possible since the module `filter_map` is `private`.
2. Using `Box<dyn StreamExt>` isn't possible either, since `StreamExt` returns `Self` in a couple of functions. I didn't want the Heap overhead in the first place though ;)

So my question is: Is there anything I could do here to get the syntactic sugar of a Trait implementation given the fact that the return type of `filter_map()` is `private` and `StreamExt` isn't object-safe? It would be cool to just use

```rust
let person_stream = receiver.transform();
```

or `into()`. Obviously I have a working implementation so this isn't really a critical question for me. But as I said at the beginning I wanted to get a deeper and better understanding about Rust in the first place.

I noticed that there is the `tokio-serde` crate, but at first glance it only deals with framed data, so I haven't dug deeper into it.

PS: 
I also faced a problem with the free function `transform` I implemented when the type inference fails. For example when handing of the new stream to a function like

```rust
async fn debug_sink<T>(mut receiver: T)
where
    T: StreamExt + Unpin,
    T::Item: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    while let Some(item) = receiver.next().await {
        println!("Item: {:#?}", item);
    }
}
```

In this case it obviously couldn't infer `T` in `transfer` in contrast to sinks like

```rust
async fn person_sink(mut receiver: impl StreamExt<Item = Person> + Unpin) {
    while let Some(person) = receiver.next().await {
        println!("Person: {:#?}", person);
    }
}
```

However I didn't want to annotate all type parameters, only the one it couldn't infer. With some trial and error I found out that I could use

```rust
transform::<Person, _, _>(stream);
```

which I was totally unaware of. I couldn't find this in the documentation, though. Is this some hidden feature, or am I just failing to properly rtfm? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you need is available in Nightly under the `type_alias_impl_trait` feature. Basically it allows you to write an associated type in a trait, and then, in the implementation, instead of writing a named type, usie the `impl BaseTrait` syntax.

I'm too lazy to write your code with a `type_alias_impl_trait` (and you didn't provide a compilable snippet) but here it is a working example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=58d8bfae946094f5de21d539f243cd9b)):

```
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

use std::fmt::Debug;

trait Foo {
    type Output: Debug;

    fn do_something() -> Self::Output;
}

impl Foo for () {
    type Output = impl Debug;

    fn do_something() -> Self::Output {
        "hello!"
    }
}
```

Note how `()::do_something` actually returns a `&'static str` but this type is never mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be what I was looking for. However I couldn't get it to work with my requirements. You might want to have a look at this example [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9fec3c88dea28ff1c2ebba8729b9006a).

Comment: @BeneSim: I think your code is mostly correct. Maybe it should be `type Output = impl StreamExt<Item = V>;`, or maybe that annotation is not needed. But note that after the error _type annotations needed_ you get a `internal compiler error`. There is a reason why this feature is still unstable...

Comment: I did try it with `type Output = impl StreamExt<Item = V>;` but it didn't work either. Guess you are right, the `rustc` crash should give me the implication that this features isn't as stable as I would want it to be, yet. Maybe I just wait until something along the lines of https://github.com/cramertj/impl-trait-goals/blob/impl-trait-in-traits/0000-impl-trait-in-traits.md gets into unstable or even stable. Until then I'll use the free function `transform`.